# Vee-Validate3: Validate backend With Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vee-validate

I used `Vee-validate@3.x.x` for Validate Backend With Laravel, following Code Below

**In My template**

```
<ValidationObserver ref="form">
    <div>
        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="name">Name</label>
        <ValidationProvider name="name" rules="required|name" v-slot="{ errors }">
            <v-text-field solo outlined dense label="Enter Name" v-model="form.name"></v-text-field>
            <span class="red--text">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
        </ValidationProvider>
    </div>
</ValidationObserver>
```

**In my Script**

```
this.$axios
    .$post(`/api/user`, this.form)
    .then(res => {
        this.form = res;
        this.getItems();
        this.$toast.info("Succeessfully Created");
        this.closeDialog();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data.errors);
        this.$refs.form.setErrors(
            err.response.data.errors
        );
    });
```

when I tried submit form the error come up

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.$refs.form.setErrors is not a function

Still no clue, whats going on...

I'll appreciate of all ur Help. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved it by changed `setErrors` to `validate`

**In my Script**

```
.catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data.errors);
        this.$refs.form.validate(
            err.response.data.errors
        );
    });
```